# How to properly add a percentage change box inside a Japanese Candlestick chart using MatPlotLibFinance on Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, visualization, candlestick-chart, mplfinance

### Context

I'm trying to figure out a good way to add **percentage price change boxes** inside a custom Japanese Candlestick chart that I have made using the [`MatPlotLibFinance`](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance) library on `Python3`, these percentage price change boxes will help to visually appreciate how much the price increased or decreased from the open price of a particular candlestick.

### Data

The following information is stored in a variable called `df`, it will be used to plot the candlestick chart

| Index | Start Date | Open Price | High Price | Low Price | Close Price | Volume | End Date | Abs((CP-OP)/CP)*100 | Low SMA 9 | Close SMA 25 | High SMA 99 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 2022-10-23 12:24:00 | 27.87 | 27.88 | 27.72 | 27.83 | 40623.0 | 2022-10-23 12:26:59.999 | 0.14 | 27.89888888888889 | 28.007600000000004 | 28.294343434343432 |
| 13 | 2022-10-23 12:27:00 | 27.83 | 27.91 | 27.83 | 27.91 | 17337.0 | 2022-10-23 12:29:59.999 | 0.29 | 27.887777777777778 | 27.997600000000002 | 28.289898989898994 |
| 14 | 2022-10-23 12:30:00 | 27.91 | 27.98 | 27.91 | 27.94 | 8235.0 | 2022-10-23 12:32:59.999 | 0.11 | 27.88222222222222 | 27.9908 | 28.286262626262626 |
| 15 | 2022-10-23 12:33:00 | 27.94 | 27.94 | 27.89 | 27.89 | 6809.0 | 2022-10-23 12:35:59.999 | 0.18 | 27.87333333333333 | 27.983599999999996 | 28.282121212121215 |
| 16 | 2022-10-23 12:36:00 | 27.89 | 27.9 | 27.85 | 27.88 | 4209.0 | 2022-10-23 12:38:59.999 | 0.04 | 27.863333333333333 | 27.973999999999997 | 28.277373737373736 |
| 17 | 2022-10-23 12:39:00 | 27.89 | 27.89 | 27.86 | 27.88 | 10082.0 | 2022-10-23 12:41:59.999 | 0.04 | 27.85666666666667 | 27.966400000000004 | 28.272121212121213 |
| 18 | 2022-10-23 12:42:00 | 27.88 | 27.89 | 27.83 | 27.88 | 13257.0 | 2022-10-23 12:44:59.999 | 0.0 | 27.846666666666668 | 27.957600000000003 | 28.26666666666667 |
| 19 | 2022-10-23 12:45:00 | 27.88 | 27.94 | 27.88 | 27.94 | 5462.0 | 2022-10-23 12:47:59.999 | 0.22 | 27.85 | 27.951999999999998 | 28.26131313131313 |
| 20 | 2022-10-23 12:48:00 | 27.93 | 28.03 | 27.93 | 28.03 | 10597.0 | 2022-10-23 12:50:59.999 | 0.36 | 27.855555555555554 | 27.9512 | 28.257070707070707 |
| 21 | 2022-10-23 12:51:00 | 28.03 | 28.06 | 27.98 | 28.05 | 10238.0 | 2022-10-23 12:53:59.999 | 0.07 | 27.884444444444444 | 27.951200000000004 | 28.253333333333334 |
| 22 | 2022-10-23 12:54:00 | 28.05 | 28.05 | 27.99 | 28.03 | 6352.0 | 2022-10-23 12:56:59.999 | 0.07 | 27.90222222222222 | 27.952800000000003 | 28.24959595959596 |
| 23 | 2022-10-23 12:57:00 | 28.02 | 28.04 | 28.0 | 28.04 | 3905.0 | 2022-10-23 12:59:59.999 | 0.07 | 27.91222222222222 | 27.9556 | 28.245656565656564 |
| 24 | 2022-10-23 13:00:00 | 28.03 | 28.05 | 28.02 | 28.03 | 4607.0 | 2022-10-23 13:02:59.999 | 0.0 | 27.926666666666666 | 27.9548 | 28.24222222222222 |
| 25 | 2022-10-23 13:03:00 | 28.04 | 28.04 | 28.0 | 28.03 | 4291.0 | 2022-10-23 13:05:59.999 | 0.04 | 27.94333333333333 | 27.956 | 28.23868686868687 |
| 26 | 2022-10-23 13:06:00 | 28.02 | 28.02 | 27.99 | 28.0 | 4856.0 | 2022-10-23 13:08:59.999 | 0.07 | 27.95777777777778 | 27.9568 | 28.234747474747476 |
| 27 | 2022-10-23 13:09:00 | 28.01 | 28.03 | 28.01 | 28.02 | 1343.0 | 2022-10-23 13:11:59.999 | 0.04 | 27.977777777777774 | 27.9584 | 28.230505050505048 |
| 28 | 2022-10-23 13:12:00 | 28.02 | 28.06 | 28.01 | 28.06 | 5932.0 | 2022-10-23 13:14:59.999 | 0.14 | 27.992222222222225 | 27.9624 | 28.226565656565658 |
| 29 | 2022-10-23 13:15:00 | 28.06 | 28.1 | 28.04 | 28.06 | 8292.0 | 2022-10-23 13:17:59.999 | 0.0 | 28.004444444444445 | 27.9656 | 28.223030303030303 |

When running `df.dtypes`, the following output is thrown:

```
Start Date             datetime64[ns]
Open Price                    float64
High Price                    float64
Low Price                     float64
Close Price                   float64
Volume                        float64
End Date               datetime64[ns]
Abs((CP-OP)/CP)*100           float64
Low SMA 9                     float64
Close SMA 25                  float64
High SMA 99                   float64
dtype: object
```

Also, another variable called `df_trading_pair_date_time_index` contains the same information as the previous variable with slight modifications, since it can only be used in this way in the script below:

```
import pandas as pd
import mplfinance as mpf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

def set_DateTimeIndex(df_trading_pair):
    df_trading_pair = df_trading_pair.set_index('Start Date', inplace=False)
    # Rename the column names for best practices
    df_trading_pair.rename(columns = { "Open Price" : 'Open',
                                       "High Price" : 'High',
                                       "Low Price" : 'Low',
                                       "Close Price" :'Close',
                              }, inplace = True)
            
    return df_trading_pair

 # Create another df just to properly plot the data
 df_trading_pair_date_time_index = set_DateTimeIndex(df)
```

### Script

The following script will execute a function called `mpl_plotting` which takes as input the variables `df`, `df_trading_pair_date_time_index` will be used to plot Japanese Candlestick chart, while the last parameter of `int` type will be used to plot the price change boxes which will then be added to the Japanese candlestick Chart:

```
def mplf_plotting(df_trading_pair, df_trading_pair_date_time_index, entry_candlestick_index):
    
    entry_price = df_trading_pair['Open Price'].iat[entry_candlestick_index]
    
    maximum_price_reached = df_trading_pair['High Price'][entry_candlestick_index+1:].max()
    maximum_price_index = df_trading_pair['Low Price'][entry_candlestick_index+1:].idxmax()
    where_values_up = [entry_candlestick_index, maximum_price_index]
    
    minimum_price_reached = df_trading_pair['Low Price'][entry_candlestick_index+1:].min()
    minimum_price_index = df_trading_pair['Low Price'][entry_candlestick_index+1:].idxmin()
    where_values_down = [entry_candlestick_index, df_trading_pair['Start Date'][minimum_price_index]]

    # Plotting
    # Create my own `marketcolors` style:
    mc = mpf.make_marketcolors(up='#2fc71e',down='#ed2f1a',inherit=True)
    # Create my own `MatPlotFinance` style:
    s  = mpf.make_mpf_style(base_mpl_style=['bmh', 'dark_background'],marketcolors=mc, y_on_right=True)    

    # Plot it
    # First create a dictionary to store the plots to add
    subplots = {'Low SMA 9': mpf.make_addplot(df_trading_pair['Low SMA 9'], width=1, color='#F0FF42'),
                'Close SMA 25': mpf.make_addplot(df_trading_pair['Close SMA 25'], width=1.5, color='#EA047E'),
                'High SMA 99': mpf.make_addplot(df_trading_pair['High SMA 99'], width=2, color='#00FFD1')}

    pct_change_boxes ={'Percentage Change Up': mpf.make_addplot(df_trading_pair, fill_between=dict(y1=entry_price,y2=maximum_price_reached,where=where_values_up),alpha=0.5,color='g'),
                       'Percentage Change Down': mpf.make_addplot(df_trading_pair, fill_between=dict(y1=entry_price,y2=minimum_price_reached,where=where_values_down),alpha=0.5,color='g')}
    
    list_of_plots = list(subplots.values())
    #for i in list(pct_change_boxes.values()):
        #list_of_plots.append(i)
    
    trading_plot, axlist = mpf.plot(df_trading_pair_date_time_index,
                        figratio=(10, 6),
                        type="candle",
                        style=s,
                        tight_layout=True,
                        datetime_format = '%H:%M',
                        ylabel = "Precio ($)",
                        returnfig=True,
                        show_nontrading=True,
                        addplot=list_of_plots
                        )
    # Plotting
    
    # Add Title
    trading_pair = "SOLBUSD"
    symbol = trading_pair.replace("BUSD","")+"/"+"BUSD"
    axlist[0].set_title(f"{symbol} - 3m", fontsize=25, style='italic', fontfamily='fantasy')

    # Find which times should be shown every 6 minutes starting at the last row of the df
    x_axis_minutes = []
    for i in range (1,len(df_trading_pair_date_time_index),2):
        x_axis_minutes.append(df_trading_pair_date_time_index.index[-i].minute)

    # Set the main "ticks" to show at the x axis
    axlist[0].xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MinuteLocator(byminute=x_axis_minutes))

    # Set the x axis label
    axlist[0].set_xlabel('Zona Horaria UTC')
    # Set the y axis range 
    ymin_value = df_trading_pair[['Low Price','Low SMA 9','Close SMA 25', 'High SMA 99']].min(axis=1).min()
    ymax_value = df_trading_pair[['High Price','Low SMA 9','Close SMA 25', 'High SMA 99']].max(axis=1).max()
    axlist[0].set_ylim([ymin_value,ymax_value])

    # Set the SMA legends
    # First set the amount of legends to add to the legend box
    axlist[0].legend([None]*(len(subplots)+2)) 
    # Then Store the legend objects in a variable called "handles", based on this script, your objects to legend will appear from the third element in this list
    handles = axlist[0].get_legend().legendHandles

    # Finally set the corresponding names for the plotted SMA trends and place the legend box to the upper left corner in the bigger plot
    axlist[0].legend(handles=handles[2:],labels=list(subplots.keys()), loc = 'upper left', fontsize = 15)

# Execute the function to plot
mplf_plotting(df, df_trading_pair_date_time_index, 14)
```

### The Problem

After running the script above, the following output is thrown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\ResetStoreX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py", line 356, in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File "c:\users\resetstorex\downloads\binance futures data\binance api key + binance wrapper\bollinger bands\timeframe - 30 minutes\binance_futures_busd-backtesting-of-moving-averages.py", line 224, in <module>
    mplf_plotting(df_trading_pair[dict_index[i]:dict_index[i]+20], df_trading_pair_date_time_index, dict_index[i]+2)

  File "c:\users\resetstorex\downloads\binance futures data\binance api key + binance wrapper\bollinger bands\timeframe - 30 minutes\binance_futures_busd-backtesting-of-moving-averages.py", line 136, in mplf_plotting
    trading_plot, axlist = mpf.plot(df_trading_pair_date_time_index,

  File "C:\Users\ResetStoreX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mplfinance\plotting.py", line 720, in plot
    ax = _addplot_columns(panid,panels,ydata,apdict,xdates,config)

  File "C:\Users\ResetStoreX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mplfinance\plotting.py", line 1014, in _addplot_columns
    yd = [y for y in ydata if not math.isnan(y)]

  File "C:\Users\ResetStoreX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mplfinance\plotting.py", line 1014, in <listcomp>
    yd = [y for y in ydata if not math.isnan(y)]

TypeError: must be real number, not Timestamp
```

[image: output image]

If I decided to remove the following lines from the function:

```
for i in list(pct_change_boxes.values()):
    list_of_plots.append(i)
```

The following output is thrown:

[image: second output]

### Desired output

I was expecting my script to print a image like the one down below, it essentially shows how much the price increased or decreased in percentage values based on the 3rd parameter passed to the `mplf_plotting` function:

[image: desired output]

### The Question

How could I fix my function to throw an output like the desired one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest thing I have come up with was to make use of the following original `MatPlotLib` functions: [`matplotlib.pyplot.text`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.text.html), [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.vlines`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.vlines.html), [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.hlines`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.hlines.html) and also fixed some minor issues in the `mplf_plotting` function in order to avoid `SettingWithCopyWarning` from `Pandas` as well as other errors I can't remember atm.

The following improvements were implemented:

1. The `mplf_plotting` will now take just a `deepcopy` of the `df` variable, and the regular `df_trading_pair_date_time_index`
2. The first thing this function will do is to reset the index of the information passed to the temporal `df_trading_pair` variable for then deleting the old `index` column left.
3. The value assigned to the `entry_candlestick_index` will now be the `the first valid index` of the `df_trading_pair` plus the necessary amount of candlesticks to get the actual location of the desired candlestick (as it was previously set as `14`, the amount to add must be `2`).
4. The values stored in the lists of `where_values_up` and `where_values_down` will now be actual `Timestamp` dates rather than its corresponding index values.
5. The percentage change values to show in the final output will be calculated in the `pct_change_up` and `pct_change_down` variables

> *Note: The following solution **doesn't end up adding an actual***
> *percentage change box to the japanese candlestick chart, but hey, it works for me atm* ¯\*(ツ)*/¯.

### Alternative Script

```
from datetime import timedelta

def mplf_plotting(df_trading_pair, df_trading_pair_date_time_index):
    
    # Reset the index
    df_trading_pair.reset_index(inplace=True)
    df_trading_pair.drop('index', inplace=True, axis=1)
    
    entry_candlestick_index = df_trading_pair.first_valid_index()+2
    
    entry_price = df_trading_pair['Open Price'].iat[entry_candlestick_index]
    
    maximum_price_reached = df_trading_pair['High Price'][entry_candlestick_index+1:].max()
    maximum_price_index = df_trading_pair['Low Price'][entry_candlestick_index+1:].idxmax()
    where_values_up = [df_trading_pair['Start Date'].iat[entry_candlestick_index], df_trading_pair['Start Date'].iat[maximum_price_index]]
    pct_change_up = round((maximum_price_reached-entry_price)/entry_price*100,2)
    
    minimum_price_reached = df_trading_pair['Low Price'][entry_candlestick_index+1:].min()
    minimum_price_index = df_trading_pair['Low Price'][entry_candlestick_index+1:].idxmin()
    where_values_down = [df_trading_pair['Start Date'].iat[entry_candlestick_index], df_trading_pair['Start Date'][minimum_price_index]]
    pct_change_down = round((minimum_price_reached-entry_price)/entry_price*100,2)

    # Plotting
    # Create my own `marketcolors` style:
    mc = mpf.make_marketcolors(up='#2fc71e',down='#ed2f1a',inherit=True)
    # Create my own `MatPlotFinance` style:
    s  = mpf.make_mpf_style(base_mpl_style=['bmh', 'dark_background'],marketcolors=mc, y_on_right=True)    

    # Plot it
    # First create a dictionary to store the plots to add
    subplots = {'Low SMA 9': mpf.make_addplot(df_trading_pair['Low SMA 9'], width=1, color='#F0FF42'),
                'Close SMA 25': mpf.make_addplot(df_trading_pair['Close SMA 25'], width=1.5, color='#EA047E'),
                'High SMA 99': mpf.make_addplot(df_trading_pair['High SMA 99'], width=2, color='#00FFD1')}
    
    list_of_plots = list(subplots.values())
    
    trading_plot, axlist = mpf.plot(df_trading_pair_date_time_index,
                        figratio=(10, 6),
                        type="candle",
                        style=s,
                        tight_layout=True,
                        datetime_format = '%H:%M',
                        ylabel = "Precio ($)",
                        returnfig=True,
                        show_nontrading=True,
                        addplot=list_of_plots
                        )    
    # Add Title
    symbol = trading_pair.replace("BUSD","")+"/"+"BUSD"
    axlist[0].set_title(f"{symbol} - 3m", fontsize=25, style='italic', fontfamily='fantasy')

    # Find which times should be shown every 6 minutes starting at the last row of the df
    x_axis_minutes = []
    for i in range (1,len(df_trading_pair_date_time_index),2):
        x_axis_minutes.append(df_trading_pair_date_time_index.index[-i].minute)
    
    # Plot and label the Maximum Positive ROI
    axlist[0].hlines(maximum_price_reached, xmin=where_values_up[0], xmax=where_values_up[1],
                     color="#06FF44", linestyle="solid", linewidth=1.5, alpha=0.7)
    axlist[0].vlines(where_values_up[0], ymin=entry_price, ymax=maximum_price_reached,
                     color="#06FF44", linestyle="solid", linewidth=1.5, alpha=0.7)
    axlist[0].text(x=where_values_up[0]+timedelta(minutes=1), y=maximum_price_reached-0.009, s=f"ROI: +{pct_change_up}%", 
                   ha="left", va="top", fontsize="14", color="#06FF44", backgroundcolor='#000000')
    
    # Plot and label the Maximum Negative ROI
    axlist[0].hlines(minimum_price_reached, xmin=where_values_down[0], xmax=where_values_down[1],
                     color="#F51912", linestyle="solid", linewidth=1.5, alpha=0.7)
    axlist[0].vlines(where_values_down[0], ymin=entry_price, ymax=minimum_price_reached,
                     color="#F51912", linestyle="solid", linewidth=1.5, alpha=0.7)
    axlist[0].text(x=where_values_up[0]+timedelta(minutes=1), y=minimum_price_reached+0.009, s=f"ROI: {pct_change_down}%", 
                   ha="left", va="bottom", fontsize="14", color="#F51912", backgroundcolor='#000000') 
    
    # Set the main "ticks" to show at the x axis
    axlist[0].xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MinuteLocator(byminute=x_axis_minutes))

    # Set the x axis label
    axlist[0].set_xlabel('Zona Horaria UTC')
    # Set the y axis range 
    ymin_value = df_trading_pair[['Low Price','Low SMA 9','Close SMA 25', 'High SMA 99']].min(axis=1).min()
    ymax_value = df_trading_pair[['High Price','Low SMA 9','Close SMA 25', 'High SMA 99']].max(axis=1).max()
    axlist[0].set_ylim([ymin_value,ymax_value])

    # Set the SMA legends
    # First set the amount of legends to add to the legend box
    axlist[0].legend([None]*(len(subplots)+2)) 
    # Then Store the legend objects in a variable called "handles", based on this script, your objects to legend will appear from the third element in this list
    handles = axlist[0].get_legend().legendHandles

    # Finally set the corresponding names for the plotted SMA trends and place the legend box to the upper left corner in the bigger plot
    axlist[0].legend(handles=handles[2:],labels=list(subplots.keys()), loc = 'upper left', fontsize = 15)

# Execute the function to plot
mplf_plotting(df.copy(deep=True), df_trading_pair_date_time_index)
```

### Output

[image: solved]